# Swift Pass parameters in a selector

Tags: ios, swift

I have this method here:

```
func displayPDF(dataParam: NSData, PDFFileParam: String)
```

Now I am trying to call this method via `NSTtimer` like so:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(FileBrowser.displayPDF(_:PDFFileParam:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

I have these two variables:

```
let PDFFile = self.data[indexPath.row]["Name"]!!.componentsSeparatedByString("\\").last                
var data: NSData!
```

I would like to use these variables to pass to the method with the `selector`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that  you need to create custom `subclass` of `NSTimer` or other way is you can use that `userInfo`, property of `NSTimer` like this way.

First change your `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` like this way.

```
let dic:[String:AnyObject] = ["pdfName" : PDFFile, "pdfData" : data]
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(FileBrowser.displayPDF(_:)), userInfo: dic as! AnyObject, repeats: false)
```

Now change your timer function `displayPDF` like this.

```
func displayPDF(timer:NSTimer) {
    if let userInfo = timer.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject] {
         print(userInfo["pdfName"])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error for this line `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(FileBrowser.displayPDF(_:)), userInfo: ["pdfName" : PDFFile, "pdfData" : data], repeats: false)`

Comment: `Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal`

Comment: I got this error `Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal` for the userInfo value

Comment: New error for this line `let dic = ["pdfName" : PDFFile, "pdfData" : data]` this is the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`